# PHP changing download locations trick

Tags: php

There are `http://www.mysite.com` and `http://www.anothersiter.com` sites. There are links to some files in `http://www.anothersite.com`:

```
http://www.anothersite.com/file1
http://www.anothersite.com/file2
...
http://www.anothersite.com/fileN
```

I would like to place above links on `http://www.mysite.com` for site visitors to be able to download. But I want them to be downloaded as if they are coming from `http://www.mysite.com` instead of `http://www.anothersite.com`. Is it possible achieve such scenario in PHP and if it is possible how?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "downloaded as if they are coming from `http://www.mysite.com`" This delves into some potential security exploits that are explicitly blocked by browsers.

Comment: Yes, you will be downloading them via your server through some type of a proxy script.

Comment: So you want to proxy requests to another site's content?

Comment: let's say there is http://www.anothersite.com/file1. This link is published on http://www.mysite.com. Normally when you click on it downloads it from http://www.anothersite.com/file1 and file name is file1 but I would like users see that if that file is coming from http://www.mysite.com/new_file_name

Comment: @datasage normally my way of doing this is to download to mysite.com server with new file name. But can I do the same procedure without downloading it to mysite.com. Maybe as you said by proxying

Comment: The data will still pass through your server. You can save the data or just pass it through directly to the end user.

Comment: @datasage exactly! How can I make it pass directly through my server?

Comment: Be prepared to pay twice of the bandwidth that your users download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple download script that downloads the file through your server using `file_get_contents`. Your php.ini will need `allow_url_fopen` enabled for this to work, though. But the code can be very simple. For example, to download a PDF file called `downloaded.pdf`, you can use this:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.coolermaster-usa.com/upload/download/85/files/product_sheet.pdf');
```

This will retrieve the product sheet as is it were downloaded from your domain:

[image: Local download]

--

**Update**

In case of MP3 downloads, you can consider to use the `Content-Disposition: inline` instead and just stream the mp3 to the browser. Like this:

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="somefile.mp3"');
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/somefile.mp3');
```

That way the file will be played in-line. People can then always press CTRL+S to download it, or just listen to it without permanently saving it somewhere (just in the temporary internet files during their session).

Comment: Better to save `file_get_contents()` output into a `$var`, and do `header("Content-Length: ".strlen($var));` before you `echo $var` so that the browser will be able to track download progress.

Comment: I see this way is slower than direct download. Is it because localhost downloads it?

Comment: Yes, your server acts as a proxy host that stores the file first. If you're planning on offering large files, using something like `fsockopen` to setup the HTTP connection through a socket will probably be faster.

Comment: @Oldskool I am offering mp3 audio files which are 4-10 mb. Any recommendations?

Comment: @torayeff In that case, I would go with embedding the mp3 inline. See the update to my answer.